# Android listview itemclick change text button

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I had a problem doing this android project. Can you help me with this problem, I want to change the text of button onItemClick.

This is my CustomerAdapter:

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.product_icons = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product_icons);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.addtocart = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnaddtocart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        holder.product_icons.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
        holder.status.setText("P" + row_pos.getStatus());
        holder.addtocart.setText(" add to cart");


       } else {

           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

       }

        return convertView;
```

Here are my code for MainActivity.java contains onitemclick listerner

```
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
       long id) {

    RowItem item = rowItems.get(position);
    String member_name = item.getMember_name();
       int product_icons = item.getProfile_pic_id();
      String status = item.getStatus();

     Button cart= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaddtocart);
     cart.setText("Added to cart");


   }
```

Comment: what happens with this code of yours initially bro? if you want to change the text then set text directly after your initialisation & why the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me kill the problem of yours..

1: get button to change when you click listview item

ans: button responds to click events.. so if you put it in listview it takes click events from the listview.. so to get over it
make

```
ListView focusable android:focusable="true"
Button not focusable android:focusable="false"
```

and also add this

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

on the listview.. it makes the listview receive focus before its child.. now you move on to the click events this is an edited version of your code

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

   RowItem item = rowItems.get(position);
   String member_name = item.getMember_name();
   int product_icons = item.getProfile_pic_id();
   String status = item.getStatus();

   Button cart= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaddtocart);
   cart.setText("Added to cart");
   Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),"Added to Cart: " + member_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

i remove some codes for cleanliness and also i remove this code

```
newadapter = new CustomAdapter(this, rowItems);
mylistview.setAdapter(newadapter);
newadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

because it sets the adapter all over again and you don't get to see the button being set
and it refreshes it also..lol.. so this is my pitches, try it and let me know if it works
also if you add items to your listview or remove items and you want to show it to the user
you dont need to re-set the adapter just call the notifyDataSetChanged() method..

EIDT 2: about your disabling the item

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(cart.getText().equals("Added to cart")){ //checking the text of button
                          arg1.setFocusable(false);
                          arg1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                          arg1.setAlpha((float)0.2);// i dont trust this line-(it works) but i want to give you the idea, there are soo many ways of making a view transparent.
                        }

                    }
```

this makes the clicked event not respond to focus and also sets it to transparent.. but if you want just the button not to respond to click events, setEnabled to false, and also focus to false..on the button "cart".  i wrote it with notepad so check for correctness of code or any codding silliness

happy codes

Comment: i want to add additional question. i want to achieve after changing the text of my button and DISABLE item click position. thank you very much.

Comment: disable item click for the listview or buttom??@paulbuscano or disable the particular item responding to click event?

Comment: if i click 3 items which is 3 text change to "added to cart". i want to disable the click event.

Comment: check my edit.. basically you check the text on the button and if its congurent with the one you want you disable or not do nothing.. so the very edit i gave you should be the first code line in the onitemclick listener and what you have should drop down in an else option get it?? @paulbuscano

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement sets the text only if the clicked item's index is 0 (iow the first item in your list/grid view). Clicking any other item won't do anything to your textview. If you just want to set text as soon as something is clicked, replace the switch statement with just cart.setText("Hello").

Comment: what would i do?. i want to achieve is when i click specific item on a listview i want to change the text of my button after click it.